# Split text area into name and email

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a text area where a user enters a few email addresses (mandatory) and names (optional). How would I split the string to get an array (or hash) of email addresses and names, taking into consideration that it could contain errors? So far, I'm able to split it into an array if no names are allowed:

```
emails = @request_feedback.emails.split("\r\n")
emails.each {|email|
  if (email =~ /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i)
    FeedbackMailer.get_feedback(current_user, email, employee_id).deliver
  end
}
```

Comment: If you allow users to enter the data in a free form manner, then there is really no way to capture email and names reliably. Regex patterns are designed to find regularly occurring patterns in text, but they might not have what your pattern matches. Without several sample of text we can't help you much because we can imagine totally different data than you receive.

Comment: Tin Man is correct. If at all possible, heavily consider refactoring your text area into discrete groups.

Comment: I was thinking about the process of splitting the contents into addresses and names, and it's an after-the-act attempt to return the data into a usable format, when, instead, you need to fix the way you capture the data. As @verbsintransit says, refactor your text area into discrete groups. I'd use a separate "Enter email:" text input, and an "Optional name:" text input. The user clicks an "Add" button and you aggregate the data into a JavaScript hash, along with adding them to the text area. When the user is done, send the hash to your code as a JSON string. Problem solved.

Comment: Ok, when I said a few it could be as many as a 100 copied contacts from an address book or spread sheet. I would give them the delimiter or pattern to use ie "address (name)" and then store/return any lines that didn't match that pattern. Still a bad idea? If so, maybe if I used a table or something along those lines it might be easier for the user than moving between text boxes and clicking the "add" button?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use groups in your regex using parentheses

```
emails.each {|email|
    if (email =~ /\A([\w+\-.]+)@([a-z\d\-.]+)\.[a-z]+\z/i)
       FeedbackMailer.get_feedback($1, email, $2).deliver
    end
}
```

Comment: This regex is nowhere close to being sophisticated enough to capture real addresses. See "[Regex use vs. Regex abuse](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/02/regex-use-vs-regex-abuse.html)" and "[I Knew How To Validate An Email Address Until I Read The RFC](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx)".

Comment: Thanks. I think I didn't explain my problem accurately. I wouldn't just let them enter the addresses and names randomly. They would have a pattern to follow ie "email (name)". I'm not very confident with regex and needed help parsing the text_area/string into email with an optional name, and handling any user typos ie ))